# How to set up parallell computing in matlab in a local network with 2 computers?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, toolbox

I have the Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox installed on two computers running Matlab (Macbook Pro i5 and Macbook Pro i7). For a thesis project, we have to shooting simulations, for which I need a lot of computer power. I know about the matlabpool option with parfor to use both cores on my local computer. Is there a way to connect the two macbooks via an ethernet cable or hub directly and configure a small local network so I can use four cores at the same time? How to set this up?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: this is correct. You should make this into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can only do this if you also acquire the Matlab Distributed Computing Server software. On its own the Parallel Computing Toolbox only provides parallel computation on a single multi-CPU/multi-core computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I was trying it with Distributed Computing Server but have troubles setting it up. I did the following:
1. Connected the computers directly with ethernet
2. Connected the computers in finder > Connect to server
3. Installed Distributed Computing Server and the Parallel Computing toolbox on both computers
4. Started the Admin Center on one of the computers
5. Added the IP adres of the other computer
6.. Got stuck here. It doesnt want to start the MDCE server...

What I simply want to reach is to use the four cores (2 on each computer) at the same time when iterating

Comment: When you pay for Matlab you get access to The Mathworks tech support.  Your question would be better addressed to them.

Comment: @user1719399 As High Performance Mark says: please contact tech support on http://www.mathworks.com/support/ and they'll help you get set up.

Answer (score 2):

On Mathworks' file exchange there is a package by [Markus Buehren](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/26973) called [Multicore - Parallel processing on multiple cores](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13775-multicore-parallel-processing-on-multiple-cores) which

> ... provides parallel processing on multiple cores on a single machine **or on multiple machines that have access to a common directory**.

To run this package, no Matlab toolboxes are needed.

The package is discussed at http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/multicore_for_matlab/ (Markus provides user support there too, I guess).